# How to get current Selected Row in dataGridview and print using crystal report?

Tags: vb.net, vb6

How to get current Selected Row in dataGridview and print using crystal reportviewer?
Print Only selected current row in data gridview

Comment: Why VB6 tag? Please elaborate on your question.

Comment: Where do you really stuck in ?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the row of your gidview into a new datatable and then bind the crystal report with this new datable and print your result.

See the second method of [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vscrystalreports/thread/8dc49602-7f05-41b1-90e9-1bdd501c77b6/#110492b2-c427-4283-b03e-3e80c2a604cc).